# Add custom form data to Drupal module without using CCK fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, cck

Iam very new to Drupal 7 so bear with me. I have created a jQueryUI drag and drop interface with JQueryUI tabs. My problem is i cant find the correct hook to add this custom interface to the admin interface. Like so (mockup) http://onlinemedia.rmcad.edu/sandBox/screenshot/screen-shot.jpg

All the examples I find are using CCK fields. CCK fields are great but they dont have this kind of custom functionality I want or does it?

Any help would very much be appreciated.

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cck is drupal 6, not 7. to add to the node creation form you could use hook_form_alter or hook_form_ID_alter.
Check the form api documentation to get an idea of how to add stuff to the form object in either of those hooks.

Comment: Is this the correct way implement this function when it comes to adding custom html,css and javascript?

function hook_form_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) 
{
  $form['dragDropImages'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('
                    <ul>

                      <li>test</li>
                      <li>test 2</li>
                      <li>test 3</li>
                      <li>test 4</li>
                      <li>test 5</li>
                    </ul>
                  '),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dragable">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
}

j

Comment: yes, that will add to the form, though you don't really need to put prefix and suffix, just put them in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

From your mockup I understand you intend to add this drag&drop interface to a content-type.

If that's the case, I'd recommend you to add the appropriate [fields](http://drupal.org/project/modules/?f%5B0%5D=im_vid_3:20224&f%5B1%5D=drupal_core:103&f%5B2%5D=bs_project_sandbox:0) first. Those would help storing the data in Drupal way, once the node is saved.

Once you are satisfied with the fields collecting the data you need, create a module and use [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) hook to integrate your "interface", the presentation layer by altering those fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add **CCK/Field** components to store your data how about you create your own database table and store your custom data in there?

This approach is a long one but I have used it to great effect on a very big and complex project.

You will need a custom module with an install script which contains the details of your custom database table.

Forgive me but I don't remember the hook for altering a node-edit-form but that is where you input the code which implement your **drag-'n'-drop** elements.

Then, you could save the settings altogether when the node-edit form is submitted but I think it's probably better to implement some **AJAX** to save the settings to your custom database table. So, when a component is dropped into it's final resting place, you use AJAX to save that information to the database.

When a user comes back to edit that page, you simply load your custom settings and apply them to the **drag-'n'-drop** features and their previous configuration(s) would be visible to them.

I do hope that makes sense and it helps you.